# ampersand before variable name on php7 doesn't work

Tags: php-7

Can you please tell me what this piece of code does and why doesn't it work on php7?

```
$var1 = test ($var2, &$var3);
```

Error code:
    **Deprecated**: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in (file name)

Answer (score 3):

Call-time pass-by-reference was deprecated in PHP 5.3:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Looking at this question and their other one, I think mmatti might be switching from 5.2 to 7.0... in which case, whoa, I can't believe their code works with so few errors